# how to run R from HTML/Java and host on Jboss/tomcat server

Tags: java, html, r, tomcat, jboss

I have Developed some google plot graphs and others graphs in R. the output here is plots with some interaction like mouse hover and update the plots for every 5 minutes (not JPEG). i want to run the r script dynamically and render it on HTML. previously i have hosted these on shiny-server using `<iframe>` to embed in HTML.

now how can i host these on different server (HTML and r on same server).

Answer (score 0):

1. By redirecting iframe content to your shiny server :

html & js like :

```
<iframe name="myFrame" ... />

js:  window.frames["iframetest"].location = "http://myshinyserver:..."
```

so two servers running ...

2. If you are using js chart libraries like ggvis, dygraphs ... and if you have to go with an app server, you should do some javascript to reproduce your graphs ....